# Dragging from one view to another in a frameset does not execute PostDragDrop

Tags: view, lotus-notes, frameset, lotusscript

I have two side-by-side views in a frameset, one outline view and one calendar view. On the calendar view, I can drag between dates, my code perfectly executing. However, when I try to drag from my outline view onto a date on the calendar view, the Postdragdrop event on the calendar view does not execute.

How can I drag/drop between views in a frameset?

Thanks.